# Javascript convert localStorage getItem string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an image gallery and I am storing the image names into localstorage using:

```
var user_selected_images = JSON.stringify(output);
localStorage.setItem('selectedFiles', user_selected_images);
```

When a image from the gallery is clicked,I want to check if the is image is present in the array.

```
var selFiles = localStorage.getItem('selectedFiles');
var selFiles = JSON.parse(selFiles);
```

When I try to assess the typeof variable

```
console.log(typeof selFiles)
```

I get an output as `string`.  Currently my getItem output looks like this:

```
["STAR_SPORTS-00001.jpg","STAR_SPORTS-00002.jpg"]
```

I tried using `jQuery.makeArray(selFiles)` and various options that I could find in SO, but still my getItem remains as string and not as array.

Comment: That sounds unlikely. I get an array if I do  `var output = ["STAR_SPORTS-00001.jpg","STAR_SPORTS-00002.jpg"];
user_selected_images = JSON.stringify(output);
console.log(user_selected_images);
var selFiles = JSON.parse(user_selected_images);
console.log(typeof selFiles,selFiles)`

Can you console.log something and perhaps there is an error somewhere

Comment: That can only happen if `output` is already a strifigied JSON. Can you try not to stringify and store it as it is.

Comment: Please update the question with the exact solution which you have.

Comment: @mplungjan I also got array. Probably OP is missing some details from the question

Comment: Ithink  `output` is already a JSON string... so this line is unnecessary `JSON.stringify(output);` ............. try `localStorage.setItem('selectedFiles', output);`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Better first do `console.log(typeof output)`

Comment: @mplungjan: yes that would help to confirm

Comment: @31piy Thank you.  In fact my php script which posts was json encoded.

Comment: Thank you all so much...I don't know which answer to accept.  Though @31piy was the most direct one...I can accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, it must return `object` not `string`. See the test below. Also use `Array.isArray()` to test it:

```js
var output = ["STAR_SPORTS-00001.jpg", "STAR_SPORTS-00002.jpg"]
var user_selected_images = JSON.stringify(output);
var selFiles = user_selected_images;
var selFiles = JSON.parse(selFiles);
console.log(typeof selFiles);
console.log(Array.isArray(selFiles));
```

Perhaps your `output` is already a JSON string, in which case you shouldn't use `JSON.stringify()` on it. Save it directly to `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem('selectedFiles', output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your `output` variable is not a string? If I initialize `output` like this:

```
var output = ["STAR_SPORTS-00001.jpg","STAR_SPORTS-00002.jpg"];
```

`console.log(typeof selFiles)` returns `object` as expected.

Then I initialize `output` like this:

```
var output = '["STAR_SPORTS-00001.jpg","STAR_SPORTS-00002.jpg"]';
```

`console.log(typeof selFiles)` returns a string like the problem you are having.